# Permisos bluetooth admin en Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, permisos, bluetooth

Estoy tratando de conseguir permisos de bluetooth en Android 6.0 pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, estoy usando el código de [este enlace](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419)

```
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
```

*Datos adicionales:*

- Mínima version para mi app: 4.0
  *Añadi los permisos en el manifest.

Comment: Este permiso no es "peligroso" únicamente necesita ser definido en el AndroidManifest.xml para ser usado @JeFNDZ

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el permiso :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

**No esta considerado como un [permiso "peligroso"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions?hl=es-419#normal-dangerous) por esa razón no necesitas realizar la petición, aún si usas un dispositivo con Android 6.0 o posterior. Es por esta razón por la cual al realizar la petición manual esta no se llama.**

Lo único que necesitas para el permiso [**BLUETOOTH_ADMIN**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=es-419#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) es su declaración dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`.

> [BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=es-419#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) agregado en API level 1
>     public static final String
>   **BLUETOOTH_ADMIN** Permite a las aplicaciones descubrir y vincular dispositivos bluetooth..
>
> **Nivel de protección: normal**
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"

Comment: muchas gracias!